# as there anyway to play flv videos in webview in iphone

Tags: iphone

As there anyway to play FLV videos in UIWebView.
 which I am loading from website through RSS Feed.

current It is playing only those Videos which are in MP4 format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO flash in iPhone

Comment: Guess you didn't get the memo then.  http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/